# catching the URL from a streaming video/audio

Tags: vlc-media-player, kodi, mpd

I am trying to get the url of a live stream ([from this German IPTV](https://www.prosieben.at/livestream)) in order to watch it using VLC and with Kodi, but instead of a .m3u8 file like usual, I am getting a .mpd file and its associated .ts files. If I open it with VLC neither audio nor video are played and not played at all with Kodi.